# AlarmManager not creating an alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm attempting to add some "reminders" functionality to my app.  I want to set up an `AlarmManager` and fire a `Notification` when the alarm happens.

I've added a few methods to create an alarm, cancel an alarm, and see if an alarm is active.

The following code is in `Settings.class` which extends `Activity`:

```
private boolean getRemindersEnabled() {
    return (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            1,
            new Intent(this, Main.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
}

private void enableReminders() {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mDayStart);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            SIXY_MINUTES,
            alarmIntent);

    mRemindersEnabled = getRemindersEnabled();
    populateReminders();
}

private void disableReminders() {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    service.cancel(pending);

    mRemindersEnabled = getRemindersEnabled();
    populateReminders();
}
```

When I call `enableReminders()`, it creates the alarm.  However, `getRemindersEnabled()` returns false.  Is there something I'm failing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRemindersEnabled()` should use the same `requestCode` from the `PendingIntent` that creates the Alarm. In this case, you are using `1`, the correct will be `0`.

```
private boolean getRemindersEnabled() {
    return (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0,
            new Intent(this, Main.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
}
```

**[EDIT]**

To cancel the Alarm, before calling `service.cancel(intent);`, call `pending.cancel();` using the flag `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent. FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
pending.cancel();
service.cancel(pending);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm a bit surprised.  My create/delete code is directly from Google's documentation on `AlarmManager`.  It was not obvious to me that parameter was an ID.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem with `disableReminders()` now.  After execute this code, `getRemindersEnabled()` does not return false.

Comment: I think is because the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` cancel the PendingIntent, and will be no longer available next time you call. Try using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: I have not tried your previous comment yet, but if I leave the screen and come back, `getRemindersEnabled()` will return false.

Comment: The suggestion in your previous comment did not solve the issue.  Also, now when I leave the screen and come back, `getRemindersEnabled()` still returns true.

Comment: Sorry, when you use PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT you need to call intent.cancel() to remove the subscription

Comment: I am calling `cancel()` on my `AlarmManager` object in that method.

Comment: Even calling `service.cancel(pending);`, Can you try calling `pending.cancel();` before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76267/discussion-between-deividi-cavarzan-and-andrew).